# Maven Cargo Deploy During Release Perform

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-cargo

Is it possible to have maven do a `cargo:redeploy` while I am doing a `release:perform`?

Currently, we do a `release:perform` which removes `-SNAPSHOT` from the version, builds, commits, and then increments the version. This places the final version WAR in the `target/` directory but running `cargo:redeploy` sees the new version number in the `pom.xml` and fails.

Is there a way to tell the cargo plugin to use the old version number or target the execution to occur after the final WAR is built but before the version is incremented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell the cargo plugin to use the old version number or target the execution to occur after the final WAR is built but before the version is incremented?

I don't see how to do this and, personally, I would decouple the cargo deployment from the release (and perform the deployment from the tagged version after the facts).

Comment: Even though we are a very small shop and this is an internal-only project where tagging a release and production deployment go hand-in-hand, this makes sense. Better to adopt good habits now even if it means having to run a whole two commands instead of one. Thanks.